# Error: Wrong export slider file format! This could be caused because the ZipArchive extension is not enabled

Tags: wordpress, php-ziparchive

I'm getting this error while trying to import sliders in Revolution Slider Wordpress plugin:

Error: Wrong export slider file format! This could be caused because the ZipArchive extension is not enabled.

In my case the ZipArchive extension is installed and active (check: http://www.digitpro.it/tools/info.php) so none of other replies on the web applies.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the `ZipArchive PHP` extension is not installed on your server.

You can see there for more info: http://portfoliotheme.org/support/forums/topic/error-importing-sample-revolution-sliders/

Answer (score 3):

When upgrading to PHP 7, you should make sure to install the PHP 7 versions of you libraries as well. The PPA providing PHP 7 also provides a php7.0-zip package. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

To see additional PHP 7 libraries that are available, run:

```
sudo apt-cache search php7.0-*
```